# How to know azure open ai model deployments running in cpu or gpu?

Tags: azure-openai

1.We understand that models are hosted in confidential infrastructure not disclosed in public domain. Is every model instance or deployment hosted in a separate dedicated infrastructure or is there a shared infrastructure within Microsoft that commonly hosts all instances?

2.When building applications based on Azure OpenAI, how do we guarantee performance/responsiveness for varying loads/usage patterns, if we do not have control over selection of the hosting hardware?

Thanks in advance.

Please share the answer related to the question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.